# Not fetch properties from config service

Tags: java, spring-cloud

GET request to config service `http://localhost:8888/dictionary/default` return valid JSON with properties.

Dictionary service fail to start without properties:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class DictionaryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DictionaryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: dictionary
  profiles:
    active: default
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: localhost:8888/dictionary
```

build.gradle

```
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

What is mistake? Why properties not fetch?

Comment: Add the http scheme to the url? Please add the logs, it will say what it tried to fetch from where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `/dictionary` path to your *cloud config uri*. Just `localhost:8888` is enough.